# laravel new routes getting 404 even after cache clear and route clear

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I'm running laravel application and recently i have added new api routes in `api.php` for new functionality

consider below is my route :

```
Route::get('/testdb', 'Controller@testDb');
```

when i am trying to run the above api, getting `404 NOT FOUND` for all the new routes

I have cleared all the cache and routes.

Here is api.php code

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'Api', 'middleware' => 'dbchange'], function () {
    Route::get('/testdb', 'Controller@testDb');
}
```

**URL : https://domain/api/v1/testdb**

**I have tried provided solution available on the stackoverflow but none of them is worked in my case**

Comment: What is the url ?

Comment: here is the url https://domain/api/v1/testdb

Comment: path `v1` is missing from your given route code. You can see the route list as `php artisan route:list`

Comment: So you have to declare route like this ```Route::get('/v1/testdb', 'Controller@testDb');```

Comment: v1 is the prefix which i have added in the api.php

Comment: Try ```php artisan route:cache```

Comment: tried all commands but not working

Comment: what is the output of `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: i can see it is register in the route list

Comment: I am not sure but i think your namespace is incorrect, it will be pointed to controller class

Comment: I have provided correct namespace

Answer (score 0):

To change that you can head over to the file, `app/providers/RouteServiceProviders.php` and change prefix to what ever name you would like in the `mapApiRoutes()` function.
But there is a catch in everything you change. The order of the prefix should be written as shown in the following code, if you want to use your API routes with and without prefixes.

```
protected function mapApiRoutes(){
  Route::prefix('{locale}/api')  //----Prefixed route here
    ->middleware('api')
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
  Route::prefix('api')
    ->middleware('api')  //----Un-prefixed route here
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

In any multiple API prefixed scenarios such as,`prefix(‘{locale}/api’)` the additional prefixed route has to be registered above the default prefix route. This way you can access an API with the prefix and without the prefix.

Comment: i am not able to understand why my newly added routes are not working and rest (the old routes) are working correctly.. Just to add one point it is working on my local machine(xampp) but it is not working on production server

Comment: I have another option, did you already solve it?

Comment: no it is not resloved..Can you help me with other option

Comment: Mansjoer can you help me with another option

Comment: Finally this has been resolved.... Here in my case the domain was internally mapped to different domain and beause of that i api routes were not able to mapped correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use this in Route::group namespace

```
'namespace' => 'Api\v1'
```

Comment: Shall i remove prefix?

Comment: No


Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\v1', 'middleware' => 'dbchange'], function () {

Comment: not working this